# ReportFolder record created but not FolderShare records?

Tags: metadata-api

Begging your understanding,

My app creates 3 FolderShare objects, a ReportFolder object, sets the FolderShare objects to the ReportFolder obj, finally creating the ReportFolder object, to wit:

```
theApp.sfConnectionSandboxMetadata = Utilities.connectToSalesforceMetadata( "conv3");

aFolderShareObjA = createFolderShareObj( "00Ge0000000LAKo", FolderShareAccessLevel.EditAllContents, FolderSharedToType.Group);
aFolderShareObjB = createFolderShareObj( "00Ge0000000LAKo", FolderShareAccessLevel.EditAllContents, FolderSharedToType.Group);
aFolderShareObjC = createFolderShareObj( "00Ge0000000LAKo", FolderShareAccessLevel.EditAllContents, FolderSharedToType.Group);

folderShare_arry = new com.sforce.soap.metadata.FolderShare[3];
folderShare_arry[0] = aFolderShareObjA;
folderShare_arry[1] = aFolderShareObjB;
folderShare_arry[2] = aFolderShareObjC;

aRepFolderObj = createReportFolderObj("RameshOwesMeLunch","RameshOwesMeATurkeySwiss",FolderAccessTypes.Public, folderShare_arry);

metadataObj_arry = new Metadata[1];
metadataObj_arry[0] =  aRepFolderObj;   

//subtlty - even though Folder is a concrete class,
//          create() wants more-complete concrete class like ReportFolder
//subtlty - had to go up from 24 to 28 on authEndPoint
AsyncResult[] ar_arry = theApp.sfConnectionSandboxMetadata.create( metadataObj_arry);
```

The app runs and completes w/o error and we do see the report folder in Salesforce BUT not the folder shares. Must I create the FolderShare objects in Salesforce first? And if so how are they created and how does one bind them to the ReportFolder object?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that not everything in the Metadata API is accessible via the [CRUD calls](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_crud_based_calls_intro.htm). You need to use the file-based [deploy()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm) function. There's [sample code](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm#sample_java_deploy) to show how this is done, passing in a [zip file containing the metadata](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/file_based_zip_file.htm).

Basically, you'll need a package.xml in the root of the zip, with content like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>FolderName1</members>
        <name>Folder</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>FolderName2</members>
        <name>Folder</name>
    </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>
```

Then, in `reports` and/or `dashboards` directories in the zip, you'll have an XML file per FolderShare with names of the form `FolderName1-meta.xml`, and content like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <folderShares>
       <accessLevel>View</accessLevel>
        <sharedTo>R1</sharedTo>
        <sharedToType>Role</sharedToType>
    </folderShares>
</ReportFolder>
```

See the [FolderShare](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_foldershare.htm) docs for more detail on the element values.

Comment: I don't think 'Folder' is a valid metadata type in this context.  It comes down with Ant when you reference the folder as a Report, Dashboard, Template, or Document type.